# Check / Uncheck corresponding checkboxes in different columns

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox

I have 2 columns 'Select' & 'Super' these columns have checkboxes, and can be selected or unselected by the user. What I am looking for is a jQuery solution to :

1. If any checkbox in Column B (super) is selected then the
   corresponding checkbox in Column A (select) should be checked
2. If any checkbox in Column A (select) is unselected, then the
   corresponding checkbox in Column B (super) should be unchecked

The HTML code that I have is:

````
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select1" checked="checked" class="select-checkbox">
</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="super1" class="super-checkbox">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="select2" class="select-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="super2" class="super-checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="select3" checked="checked" class="select-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="super3" checked="checked" class="super-checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="select4" checked="checked" class="select-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="super4" checked="checked" class="super-checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>```
````

Comment: What solutions did you try when you attempted to solve this problem, what went wrong, or didn’t work? Please add your javascript/jQuery code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a common class to all select checkboxes, and a common class to all super checkboxes

```js
$(function(){
  $('.super-checkbox').change(function(e){
    const chk = $(this);
    if(chk.is(':checked')){
      //Super is checked
      // get the closest tr
      const tr = chk.closest('tr');
      //find the select checkbox, under this tr
      const selectChk = tr.find('.select-checkbox');
      //Check this select checkbox
      selectChk.prop('checked',true);
    }
  });
  
  $('.select-checkbox').change(function(e){
    const chk = $(this);
    if(!chk.is(':checked')){
      //Select is not checked
      // get the closest tr
      const tr = chk.closest('tr');
      //find the super checkbox, under this tr
      const selectChk = tr.find('.super-checkbox');
      //un-Check this select checkbox
      selectChk.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select1" checked="checked" class="select-checkbox">
</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="super1" class="super-checkbox">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="select2" class="select-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="super2" class="super-checkbox hrpda-interview-super-checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="select3" checked="checked" class="select-checkbox hrpda-interview-select-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="super3" checked="checked" class="super-checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="select4" checked="checked" class="select-checkbox">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="super4" checked="checked" class="super-checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this works perfectly and it was what I was looking for. Thank you very much.